# How to add an Gradient Layer to Image inside an CollectionView Cell

Tags: swift, cagradientlayer

I have custom Collection View Cell which contains ImageViews and labels. I want to add gradient colour to the image view.

I tried all the possible solutions like adding mask and adding gradient to sublayer of the image. But nothing works, guide me in solving this issue

```
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.frame = self.asanasImage.layer.bounds
    gradientLayer.colors = [UIColor.clear.cgColor,UIColor.black.cgColor]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.7,1.2]
    self.asanasImage.layer.addSublayer(gradientLayer)
```

Comment: Please share the screenshot for how the imageView looks like in collectionViewCell. Where did you add the code ? in awakeNib or some where else ?

Comment: I added in  the code in init()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hie ! Trying setting the gradient for your imageView in the method

`cellForItemAt(_ indexpath: IndexPath)` method as its in a collection View Cell.

Use this method

```
func setGradientBackground(imageView: UIImageView, colorTop: UIColor, colorBottom: UIColor) {
        let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientLayer.colors = [colorBottom.cgColor, colorTop.cgColor]
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 1.0)
        gradientLayer.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)
        gradientLayer.locations = [0, 1]
        gradientLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        imageView.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 0)
    }
```

Finally inside the `cellForItemAt(_ indexpath: IndexPath)` set the gradient of the imageView like so

```
setGradientBackground(imageView: cell.your_image_View, colorTop: any_color, colorBottom: any_color)
```

Customise the method according to your needs and the colors you want for your gradient.

Hope i was able to help. If it works lemme know and vote up please ! Thank You :D

Comment: Thanks bro for helping. I will try and let you know about the progress